# Drag & Drop WPF-object inside boundaries

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls

I want to create a user-control where I can move an object (like a rectangle) within certain boundaries via drag & drop.

The drag shall be limited to the x-axis only (think of a slider).

How do I do this?

Comment: What is your initial approach?

Comment: putting a Rectangle into another Rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of **Canvas** as a base control and then add any number of WPF control to the base Canvas.  Then capture the MouseX position and reset the selected child control's Left position using **Canvas.SetLeft** when user click and drag the control.

Here is one good article [link](http://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/wpf-simple-adorner-usage-with-drag-and-resize-operations/) which will help you get started.